# URL query with encoding error on Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have this `shiny app` that uses an `query` in the `url` as an argument inside the code. 
like this: `www.shinyapp.com/?lookfor=subject`

The problem is that when i type an subject that uses accent, like this:

```
"ciência da informação"
```

it returns

```
"ciÃªncia da informaÃ§Ã£o"
```

and then the app crashes.

How could i solve this? Is it an encoding problem that can be solved inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

After all it was a simple encoding error that could be solved using the `incov()` function, to convert the character string from `UTF-8` to `latin1//TRANSLIT`

```
x <- "ciÃªncia da informaÃ§Ã£o"
iconv(x, from="UTF-8", to="latin1//TRANSLIT")
x
>"ciência da informação"
```